# live update network graph and labels in anychart graph

Tags: anychart

I am wondering if there is a way lo live update nodes and node labels.
it seems to me that the function set and .append is not working on the network graph.
https://playground.anychart.com/yJyq7cMc/1

Maybe someone can help?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to update the label's content or add/replace points, then you need to apply to the chart the updated data.
For details, check [the live sample](https://playground.anychart.com/2sSXrf17).

If you need to change the label's appearance settings, then you can call the label's API on the fly after the got rendered.